# SQL: Recursive query

Tags: sql, recursion

I've been trying to figure out how to determine how many employees have been hired after a specific employee named Blake.  I want to use a recursive query.  I have tried the following query to no avail:

```
Select E.Ename, E.Hiredate
From EMPLOYEES E, EMPLOYEES B
Where e.Hiredate = b.Hiredate
and e.Hiredate > b.Hiredate
and b.Ename = 'blake';
```

My thinking was that I join the Employees table to itself via 'e.Hiredate = b.Hiredate', what am I missing?

Comment: `Where e.Hiredate = b.Hiredate
and e.Hiredate > b.Hiredate` That will yield an empty result set.

Comment: Correct.  Where I become lost is how to compare the hiredate of all employees to blakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would have worked if you didn't have both

```
      e.Hiredate = b.Hiredate
  and e.Hiredate > b.Hiredate
```

I hope you can see how the 2 values cannot ̲*s̲i̲m̲u̲l̲t̲a̲n̲e̲o̲u̲s̲l̲y̲* be equal and unequal!!

```
Select E.Ename, E.Hiredate
From EMPLOYEES E, EMPLOYEES B
Where e.Hiredate > b.Hiredate
and b.Ename = 'blake';
```

Of course, since you are asking a fairly basic 101 question, I assume only ONE employee can be named 'blake' (i.e. `Ename` is a unique identifier), otherwise there are other logical holes to pick.

Since you're starting in SQL, I would also advise you to use ANSI joins instead of the table-list (comma) form, which would look like this:

```
Select E.Ename, E.Hiredate
  From EMPLOYEES E
  JOIN EMPLOYEES B on e.Hiredate > b.Hiredate
 WHERE b.Ename = 'blake';
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
SELECT Ename, Hiredate
FROM employees
WHERE hiredate > (SELECT TOP 1 hiredate FROM employees WHERE ename = 'blake')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.*
from employees e
where hiredate > (select max(hiredate)
                  from employees
                  where ename = 'blake');
```

The `max()` in the inner query is necessary to ensure that only a single row is returned, even if there are more employees with that name